# Background Picture in webpage

Tags: html, xampp, bootstrap-4

CSS and below is the HTML

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Grayscale v5.0.2 (https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale)
 * Copyright 2013-2018 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-grayscale/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */#mainNav{min-height:56px;background-color:#fff}#mainNav .navbar-toggler{font-size:80%;padding:.75rem;color:#64a19d;border:1px solid #64a19d}#mainNav .navbar-toggler:focus{outline:0}#mainNav .navbar-brand{color:#161616;font-weight:700;padding:.9rem 0}#mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item:hover{color:fade(white,80%);outline:0;background-color:transparent}#mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item:active,#mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item:focus{outline:0;background-color:transparent}@media (min-width:992px){#mainNav{padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;border-bottom:none;background-color:transparent;-webkit-transition:background-color .3s ease-in-out;transition:background-color .3s ease-in-out}#mainNav .navbar-brand{padding:.5rem 0;color:rgba(255,255,255,.5)}#mainNav .nav-link{-webkit-transition:none;transition:none;padding:2rem 1.5rem;color:rgba(255,255,255,.5)}#mainNav .nav-link:hover{color:rgba(255,255,255,.75)}#mainNav .nav-link:active{color:#fff}#mainNav.navbar-shrink{background-color:#fff}#mainNav.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand{color:#161616}#mainNav.navbar-shrink .nav-link{color:#161616;padding:1.5rem 1.5rem 1.25rem;border-bottom:.25rem solid transparent}#mainNav.navbar-shrink .nav-link:hover{color:#64a19d}#mainNav.navbar-shrink .nav-link:active{color:#467370}#mainNav.navbar-shrink .nav-link.active{color:#64a19d;outline:0;border-bottom:.25rem solid #64a19d}}.masthead{position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;min-height:35rem;padding:15rem 0;background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(22,22,22,.1)),color-stop(75%,rgba(22,22,22,.5)),to(#161616)),url(../img/bg-masthead3.jpg);background:linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(22,22,22,.1) 0,rgba(22,22,22,.5) 75%,#161616 100%),url(../img/bg-masthead3.jpg);background-position:center;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:scroll;background-size:cover}.masthead h1{font-family:'Varela Round';font-size:2.5rem;line-height:2.5rem;letter-spacing:.8rem;background:-webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.9),rgba(255,255,255,0));-webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;-webkit-background-clip:text}.masthead h2{max-width:20rem;font-size:1rem}@media (min-width:768px){.masthead h1{font-size:4rem;line-height:4rem}}@media (min-width:992px){.masthead{height:100vh;padding:0}.masthead h1{font-size:6.5rem;line-height:6.5rem;letter-spacing:.8rem}.masthead h2{max-width:30rem;font-size:1.25rem}}.btn{-webkit-box-shadow:0 .1875rem .1875rem 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1)!important;box-shadow:0 .1875rem .1875rem 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1)!important;padding:1.25rem 2rem;font-family:'Varela Round';font-size:80%;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:.15rem;border:0}.btn-primary{background-color:#64a19d}.btn-primary:hover{background-color:#4f837f}.btn-primary:focus{background-color:#4f837f;color:#fff}.btn-primary:active{background-color:#467370!important}.about-section{padding-top:10rem;background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#161616),color-stop(75%,rgba(22,22,22,.9)),to(rgba(22,22,22,.8)));background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#161616 0,rgba(22,22,22,.9) 75%,rgba(22,22,22,.8) 100%)}.about-section p{margin-bottom:5rem}.projects-section{padding:10rem 0}.projects-section .featured-text{padding:2rem}@media (min-width:992px){.projects-section .featured-text{padding:0 0 0 2rem;border-left:.5rem solid #64a19d}}.projects-section .project-text{padding:3rem;font-size:90%}@media (min-width:992px){.projects-section .project-text{padding:5rem}.projects-section .project-text hr{border-color:#64a19d;border-width:.25rem;width:30%}}.signup-section{padding:10rem 0;background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(22,22,22,.1)),color-stop(75%,rgba(22,22,22,.5)),to(#161616)),url(../img/bg-signup.jpg);background:linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(22,22,22,.1) 0,rgba(22,22,22,.5) 75%,#161616 100%),url(../img/bg-signup.jpg);background-position:center;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:scroll;background-size:cover}.signup-section .form-inline input{-webkit-box-shadow:0 .1875rem .1875rem 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1)!important;box-shadow:0 .1875rem .1875rem 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1)!important;padding:1.25rem 2rem;height:auto;font-family:'Varela Round';font-size:80%;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:.15rem;border:0}.contact-section{padding:5rem 0 0}.contact-section .card{border:0;border-bottom:.25rem solid #64a19d}.contact-section .card h4{font-size:.8rem;font-family:'Varela Round';text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:.15rem}.contact-section .card hr{border-color:#64a19d;border-width:.25rem;width:3rem}.contact-section .social{margin-top:5rem}.contact-section .social a{text-align:center;height:3rem;width:3rem;background:rgba(255,255,255,.1);border-radius:100%;line-height:3rem;color:rgba(255,255,255,.3)}.contact-section .social a:hover{color:rgba(255,255,255,.5)}.contact-section .social a:active{color:#fff}body{font-family:Nunito;letter-spacing:.0625em}a{color:#64a19d}a:focus,a:hover{text-decoration:none;color:#3c6360}.bg-black{background-color:#161616!important}.bg-primary{background-color:#64a19d!important}.text-primary{color:#64a19d!important}footer{padding:5rem 0}
```

```html
 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Grayscale - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
    <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/grayscale.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body id="page-top">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">iSalon</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          Menu
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#projects">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#signup">Devs</a>
            </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="login.html">Login</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="masthead">
      <div class="container d-flex h-100 align-items-center">
        <div class="mx-auto text-center">
          <h1 class="mx-auto my-0 text-uppercase">iSalon</h1>
          <h2 class="text-white-50 mx-auto mt-2 mb-5"><i>"Style on the go, wherever you go."</i></h2>
    <!-- for admin only   <h2 class="text-white-50 mx-auto mt-2 mb-5"><b>(Admin Mode)</b></h2>    -->
          <a href="#about" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Learn About iSalon</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- About Section -->
    <section id="about" class="about-section text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
            <h2 class="text-white mb-4">About iSalon</h2>
            <p class="text-white-50">Getting our haircuts or nails polished or even having a massage </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img src="img/ipad.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Projects Section -->
    <section id="projects" class="projects-section bg-light">
      <div class="container">

        <!-- Featured Project Row -->
        <div class="row align-items-center no-gutters mb-4 mb-lg-5">
          <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-7">
            <img class="img-fluid mb-3 mb-lg-0" src="img/bg-masthead.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-5">
            <div class="featured-text text-center text-lg-left">
              <h4>Shoreline</h4>
              <p class="text-black-50 mb-0">Grayscale is open source and MIT licensed. This means you can use it for any project - even commercial projects! Download it, customize it, and publish your website!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Project One Row -->
        <div class="row justify-content-center no-gutters mb-5 mb-lg-0">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/demo-image-01.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="bg-black text-center h-100 project">
              <div class="d-flex h-100">
                <div class="project-text w-100 my-auto text-center text-lg-left">
                  <h4 class="text-white">Misty</h4>
                  <p class="mb-0 text-white-50">An example of where you can put an image of a project, or anything else, along with a description.</p>
                  <hr class="d-none d-lg-block mb-0 ml-0">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Project Two Row -->
        <div class="row justify-content-center no-gutters">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/demo-image-02.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-first">
            <div class="bg-black text-center h-100 project">
              <div class="d-flex h-100">
                <div class="project-text w-100 my-auto text-center text-lg-right">
                  <h4 class="text-white">Mountains</h4>
                  <p class="mb-0 text-white-50">Another example of a project with its respective description. These sections work well responsively as well, try this theme on a small screen!</p>
                  <hr class="d-none d-lg-block mb-0 mr-0">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Signup Section -->
    <section id="signup" class="signup-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 mx-auto text-center">

            <i class="far fa-paper-plane fa-2x mb-2 text-white"></i>
            <h2 class="text-white mb-5">Interested to join in?</h2>

            <form class="form-inline d-flex">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto">Sign up now!</button>
            </form>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Contact Section -->
    <section class="contact-section bg-black">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0">
            <div class="card py-4 h-100">
              <div class="card-body text-center">
                <i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt text-primary mb-2"></i>
                <h4 class="text-uppercase m-0">Address</h4>
                <hr class="my-4">
                <div class="small text-black-50">4923 Market Street, Orlando FL</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0">
            <div class="card py-4 h-100">
              <div class="card-body text-center">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope text-primary mb-2"></i>
                <h4 class="text-uppercase m-0">Email</h4>
                <hr class="my-4">
                <div class="small text-black-50">
                  <a href="#">hello@yourdomain.com</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0">
            <div class="card py-4 h-100">
              <div class="card-body text-center">
                <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt text-primary mb-2"></i>
                <h4 class="text-uppercase m-0">Phone</h4>
                <hr class="my-4">
                <div class="small text-black-50">+1 (555) 902-8832</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="social d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" class="mx-2">
            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="mx-2">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="mx-2">
            <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="bg-black small text-center text-white-50">
      <div class="container">
        Copyright &copy; Your Website 2018
      </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
    <script src="js/grayscale.min.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

I am new at bootstrap and I got a template from the web. It is inside a folder and the file is in html. I have made another separate file of folder that contains a simple php login form. When i turned in for my xampp and went to localhost. so when I opened my downloaded template (via dragging the html file). It looked like this

[image]

I have modified the background picture. And tried to connect my login (login button directs to login form) form with this and opening it via xampp but this pops up.

[image]

Did I miss something in my css? I have checkede and it was all the same. Please someone help

Comment: Please provide us with the CSS, and the necessary HTML that accompanies it. That way, we can better help you in a way that orients to your code specifically!

Comment: I have provided sir, edited just now. I really need help as I don't understand what is happening